# Search through favorite questions, is it possible?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see many questions on meta about how to group favorites; most of the answers on those questions are:

> Use your browser's bookmark

This can accomplish the main goal: store the link to the specific page. But bookmarks are not shared between browsers/devices, and there are some other inconveniences.

But there is another thing which cannot be resolved through bookmarking: how to search via my favorites?

I have a lot of them and I want to find some specific question. How can I do this?

Comment: Funny you should ask this. I was thinking about the same thing a year or so ago but didn't ask about it.

Comment: Which arcane browser doesn't share bookmarks amongst devices these days? (just saying: it is good that people have a workaround that solves your problem... As feature requests rarely rarely almost never get anything to change UI wise here).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the search parameter **infavorites** in Stack Overflow search.

e.g: *infavorites:mine Git*

More parameters can be found by clicking on advanced search tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=&mixed=1)

Comment: Is there link to this page from interface?

Comment: @EugenKonkov set the cursor in the searchbar and click on search icon without adding entry

Comment: No intuitive, but works. Thank you.

Comment: _infavorites:mine_ sounds like an epic way to say _not my favorites_ (imagine the words spoken by a [dark lord](https://xkcd.com/1771/))